# Trying to play .mp4 file in beamer, two issues: 1) "play/pause"button not working; 2) how to set a specified time length for the video to play?

Tags: beamer, media9, video

I am trying to insert a .mp4 file in beamer, I got it work but two issues arising:

1. the "play/pause" button doesn't work;
2. I want to set a timer that the video only plays a specified time length, e.g. 10s with no looping.

Can anyone help fix my issues? Video attached. Thanks!

```
\usepackage{media9}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Video example}

\includemedia[label=largecell,
    width=\textwidth,height=0.5625\textwidth,
    activate=onclick,
    addresource=largecell.mp4,
    flashvars={
        source=largecell.mp4
       &sclaeMode=letterbox
    }
]{}{VPlayer.swf}

\mediabutton[
  mediacommand=largecell:playPause,
  jsaction=largecell:{
    try{app.clearTimeOut(tout)}catch(e){} % kill pending timers
    var tout=app.setTimeOut('annotRM.largecell.callAS("pause")', 10000);
  }
]{\fbox{Play/Pause}}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[This is the link for my video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1f4biZFfvS899QS49yPu3L8etLDjYOWy4/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: `media9` depends on FlashPlayer that was removed from the web and from Adobe products at the beginning of 2021. Controlling video and audio playback with separate buttons, as in the example, does not work anymore.